# CoreAudio: recording sound from other apps

Tags: iphone, core-audio, jailbreak

I'm thinking about creating a plugin for jailbroken iPhones to record audio from apps.
Because I'm new to CoreAudio I want to ask first if that would be possible? (so I don't invest dozens of hours in CoreAudio without even having a chance to do what I want ;))

So what do you guys think? Any tips?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nevermind, figured an interesting way out: I catch the AudioUnit when it is being initialized, then add another Callback and write it to file

Comment: Hi YllierDev, I am looking for the exact same thing. Could please provide a little more detail as to how you did this? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, haven't been here for quite some time. here is some rough code based on an example by apple and using MobileSubstrate:http://pastie.org/1882125

Comment: @YllierDev the link says server not available to handle the request

Comment: @YllierDev How do I use the methods in this class? I included it in my project but my main method can't import this class.Nor can I create an object of the class defined in pastie.mm